# Check variable(string) against folder to see if file exists

Tags: javascript

Edit: This is for a landing page which is hosted on a server along with the image directory. The locations that are fed through the URL are based on customer data. The objective is to show a personalized image based on that data.

I am dynamically feeding a string into a variable.
 
The string is collected from the URL and then split at each iteration of "_"

```
var urlStr = window.location.href; //Germany_France_Spain
var urlStrDecode = decodeURI(urlStr);
var urlStrSplit = urlStrDecode.split('_');
```

Each iteration is stored as one of three variables. One of the three could be the variable `foo`, which could be fed "Germany" for example. So:

```
var foo = urlStrSplit[1];
console.log(foo); //Germany
```

I would like to check the variable `foo` against an **image folder**  to see if the string contained exists there.

Spain.jpg
Italy.jpg
France.jpg

And if it doesn't, which in the above case would be true. I would like to do *something*.

I am unsure how I would write this as something like an `if` statement.

Thank you for any suggestions / help / advice

Neil.

Comment: You want to access the user's filesystem from the browser?

Comment: You could loop over all images and check if the content of `foo`is a substring of that current name.

Comment: @MinusFour Apologies. This is for a landing page which is hosted on a server along with the image directory. The locations that are fed through the URL are based on customer data. The objective is to show a personalized image based on that data.

Comment: @NeilMorgan you could do a HTTP query to that resource and if you get a `404` code then do something about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a library such as https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html to access the file system, you can use a method such as `fs.readdirSync` to read the filenames in a folder. This function returns the filenames as a string array. You can split the country input to get each country name. Then you can iterate through image filenames and check if any of the countries are present in it:

```js
let imageFiles = fs.readdirSync('dir-name'); //['Spain.jpg', 'Italy.jpg', 'France.jpg']
let urlStrSplit = urlStrDecode.split('_'); // your string split from above. Eg, ['Germany', 'France', 'Poland']

function contains(imageFiles, country) {
  for(image of imageFiles) {
    if(image.includes(country))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

for(country of urlStrSplit) {
  if(!contains(imageFiles, country)) {
    // DO SOMETHING
  }
}
```